# print exit code in cmd in windows os

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, windows-command-prompt

print exit code in cmd in windows os ....some command return exit code ...where this code store...and i want to print this exit code and assign it to variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`echo %ERRORLEVEL%`

Comment: Note that this will be overshadowed if a variable named `ERRORLEVEL` already exists. So be sure to clear such a variable beforehand for maximum robustness.